# Arduino accept push alert

Tags: networking, arduino, alert, esp8266

I'm trying to design a hardware project using a ESP8266.  I'd like it to interact with events sent to it from an app in the cloud.  So for example, if I wanted the Arduino to blink an LED whenever the DrudgeReport siren is active...how do I do this?
1. Have the Arduino constantly monitoring the website?  But what if there are 1000 Arduino's?  That's a lot of wasted network requests.

Is there a way (if I had a running app in the cloud) to 'push' a notification to all my Arduino's.
Do you know of any framework or tool to assist this concept?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like `SUBSCRIBE`/`PUBLISH` in `Redis` or some `IRC` server running on my server (or whole IRC server network) and some simple IRC client implementation on Arduino side. At least IRC Network should be able to handle almost anything. Standalone IRC server is usually limited around 1000 clients or less.

Or own server application suited for this better and if you do it properly, you can also overcome 1024 file descriptors per process limit and so on.

Comment: This is brilliant.  Thank you.  I need to do some research on Redis and IRC.

Comment: How about Firebase?

Comment: It looks like it might work too. The XMPP is protocol used by Jabber.